# PDF.js not showing rendered canvas image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf.js

I have a React component that shows PDFs. When I use this component, I just need to pass the PDF URL.

```
<Previewer pdfUrl={pdfUrl}></Previewer>
```

The component handles the preview details. The issue I'm facing is that this component does not show the PDF. Am I missing something? What should I do to fix this issue? Below is a demo:

```js
const { StrictMode, useRef } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

const styles = {};

const Previewer = (props) => {

    const canvasRef = useRef(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (props.pdfUrl) {
            initPdf(props.pdfUrl);
        }
    }, []);
    
    // Converted async/await function to use promise because Stack Snippet's Babel version does not support async/await
    const initPdf = (pdfUrl) => {
        // Reference CDN version of PDF.js instead of using ES6 import
        const pdfJS = pdfjsLib;
        pdfJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@3.9.179/build/pdf.worker.js";
        return pdfJS.getDocument({
            url: pdfUrl,
            cMapUrl: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@3.9.179/cmaps/',
            cMapPacked: true,
        }).promise.then((pdf) => {
            const totalPages = pdf.numPages;
            for (let i = 0; i < totalPages; i++) {
                renderPdfPage(pdf, pdfJS, i + 1);
            }
        });
    }
    
    // Converted async/await function to use promise because Stack Snippet's Babel version does not support async/await
    const renderPdfPage = (pdf, pdfJS, pageNum) => {
        return pdf.getPage(pageNum).then((page) => {
            const viewport = page.getViewport({
                scale: 1.0
            });
            let divPage = window.document.createElement("div");
            if(!canvasRef || !canvasRef.current) return;
            let canvas = divPage.appendChild(window.document.createElement("canvas"));
            const canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;
            const renderContext = { canvasContext, viewport };
            const renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
            renderTask.promise.then(function () {
                const textContent = page.getTextContent();
                return textContent;
            }).then(function (textContent) {
                const textLayer = document.querySelector(`.${styles.textLayer}`);
                if (!textLayer) return;
                textLayer.style.left = canvas.offsetLeft + 'px';
                textLayer.style.top = canvas.offsetTop + 'px';
                textLayer.style.height = canvas.offsetHeight + 'px';
                textLayer.style.width = canvas.offsetWidth + 'px';
                textLayer.style.setProperty('--scale-factor', '1.0');
                pdfJS.renderTextLayer({
                    textContentSource: textContent,
                    container: textLayer,
                    viewport: viewport,
                    textDivs: []
                });
            });
            canvasRef.current.appendChild(divPage);
        });
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.cavasLayer}>
            <canvas id="the-cavas" ref={canvasRef} />
            {/**<div className={styles.textLayer}></div>**/}
        </div>
    );
}

const pdfUrl = "https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf"
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><Previewer pdfUrl={pdfUrl} /></StrictMode>);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@3.9.179/build/pdf.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I've made your code runnable. Would you be able to share the styles? There's a variable named `styles` that currently has an empty object assigned to it. Could you modify this to include your styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

In the `renderPdfPage` function you create a `div` element that holds a `canvas` element that has the rendered PDF page. These `div`s are then appended to a `canvas` element. However descendents of the `canvas` element are not rendered if the `canvas` element is supported by the browser. From the [spec for the `canvas` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#the-canvas-element):

> When authors use the [`canvas`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#the-canvas-element) element, they must also provide content that, when presented to the user, conveys essentially the same function or purpose as the [`canvas`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#the-canvas-element)'s bitmap. This content may be placed as content of the [`canvas`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#the-canvas-element) element. The contents of the [`canvas`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#the-canvas-element) element, if any, are the element's [`fallback content`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#fallback-content).

The definition of [fallback content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#fallback-content) is:

> Some embedded content elements can have **fallback content**: content that is to be used when the external resource cannot be used (e.g. because it is of an unsupported format). The element definitions state what the fallback is, if any.

## Solution

You'll need to change the parent `canvas` to a suitable element. I've used a `div` in the demo below:

```js
const { StrictMode, useRef } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

const styles = {};

const Previewer = (props) => {

    const pdfContainerRef = useRef(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (props.pdfUrl) {
            initPdf(props.pdfUrl);
        }
    }, []);
    
    // Converted async/await function to use promise because Stack Snippet's Babel version does not support async/await
    const initPdf = (pdfUrl) => {
        // Reference CDN version of PDF.js instead of using ES6 import
        const pdfJS = pdfjsLib;
        pdfJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@3.9.179/build/pdf.worker.js";
        return pdfJS.getDocument({
            url: pdfUrl,
            cMapUrl: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@3.9.179/cmaps/',
            cMapPacked: true,
        }).promise.then((pdf) => {
            const totalPages = pdf.numPages;
            for (let i = 0; i < totalPages; i++) {
                renderPdfPage(pdf, pdfJS, i + 1);
            }
        });
    }
    
    // Converted async/await function to use promise because Stack Snippet's Babel version does not support async/await
    const renderPdfPage = (pdf, pdfJS, pageNum) => {
        return pdf.getPage(pageNum).then((page) => {
            const viewport = page.getViewport({
                scale: 1.0
            });
            let divPage = window.document.createElement("div");
            if(!pdfContainerRef || !pdfContainerRef.current) return;
            let canvas = divPage.appendChild(window.document.createElement("canvas"));
            const canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;
            const renderContext = { canvasContext, viewport };
            const renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
            renderTask.promise.then(function () {
                const textContent = page.getTextContent();
                return textContent;
            }).then(function (textContent) {
                const textLayer = document.querySelector(`.${styles.textLayer}`);
                if (!textLayer) return;
                textLayer.style.left = canvas.offsetLeft + 'px';
                textLayer.style.top = canvas.offsetTop + 'px';
                textLayer.style.height = canvas.offsetHeight + 'px';
                textLayer.style.width = canvas.offsetWidth + 'px';
                textLayer.style.setProperty('--scale-factor', '1.0');
                pdfJS.renderTextLayer({
                    textContentSource: textContent,
                    container: textLayer,
                    viewport: viewport,
                    textDivs: []
                });
            });
            pdfContainerRef.current.appendChild(divPage);
        });
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.cavasLayer}>
            <div id="pdf-container" ref={pdfContainerRef} />
            {/**<div className={styles.textLayer}></div>**/}
        </div>
    );
}

const pdfUrl = "https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf"
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><Previewer pdfUrl={pdfUrl} /></StrictMode>);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@3.9.179/build/pdf.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```